# Using vim as an external tool in intellij idea

Tags: git, vim, intellij-idea, vim-fugitive

I want to use `vim` editor as an external tool in intellij idea. I mapped a `Ctrl-U` combination to opening the current file with `vim`. Then I want to use the `fugitive` plugin, which is a wrapper over `git` and uses the `git` binary. But the `vim` opened from idea cannot locate the `git` binary. When I start the vim from shell, it can locate the `vim` binary.

```
/bin/bash: git: command not found
```

Comment: idea has a vim plugin

Comment: echo $PATH at vim shell

Comment: @farmer1992: there is `/usr/bin` there, so I `ln -s`ed to `git` binary from there, it's kind of quick fix

Answer (score 1):

When launched from the IDE, vim doesn't seem to inherit the environment variables (like `PATH`) that you set in your `~/*rc`. You could try toprepend the correct `PATH` to your command. Something like:

```
PATH=/path/to/git:$PATH /usr/bin/gvim
```

Comment: there is only a space for entering the command in the External tools dialog in idea. I cannot preset some variables in the form.